# Wordpress posts having odd issue all of a sudden

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm running into an odd problem on my Wordpress site ( www.ez007.net). My most recent posts don't finish loading properly. The last two pieces that usually load on my page is the green vote buttons and the text in the right sidebar. But for some reason the page stops loading and these elements stay unloaded. Images below to explain

**An older good post, you can see the red and green vote buttons are working and the text in the right hand sidebars looks clean:**

[image: An older good post, you can see the red and green vote buttons are working and the text in the right hand sidebars looks clean]

**One of the newer posts with issues, see the red and green vote button are not showing and the text in the right hand sidebar is all ski-whiff:**

[image: One of the newer posts with issues, see the red and green vote button are not showing and the text in the right hand sidebar is all ski-whiff]

This only occurs on the last 10 or so posts on my website, and I made no changes to code or anything else when this started occurring.

It's really hard to explain and I can't even begin to understand how I can start troubleshooting this issue.

Any help would be amazing, I'll add the HTML output from both pages. Please let me know what else is needed? Thanks.

I realize there are errors in the code but I'm in the process of working those out, and the theme was working fine for a number of weeks before this issue started occurring.

Comment: Unfortunately it is also hard for us to debug your issue based on images without random guesses. And I don't think your HTML will help. It looks like a CSS/Javascript issue. Sorry but this kind of question is not a good topic for this site and will probably be closed. I think you will have to contract a developer to investigate your issue.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console when you load the page? Right click on the page and click "Inspect" and then open the console and see if there are any errors.

Comment: Sounds like you should begin by debugging your theme and any widgets and plugins you use.

Comment: Thanks guys,  cant understand why this started happening out of no where? same plugins and theme that ive had for weeks, and was working fine? thanks again for all your replies, means alot to have such helpful people

Comment: even the wordpress Black bar at the top wont show on these pages.... weird!

Answer (score 0):

**The problem lies in a missing CSS file on the templates with the issue - on the home page the following CSS file is referenced :**

`http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/style/wpp.css?ver=3.3.4`

**The link tag for this CSS file is missing on [this page](http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/free-samples/pet-products/free-150g-bag-of-purina-one-salmon-tuna-cat-food/):**

You've probably got to fix that wherever your `wp_enqueue_style()` calls for that particular template are made.

**The reason the issue is occuring:**

The `wpp.css` file contains the rules for the class `wpp-thumbnail` this class applies `display: inline` and `float: left` to the thumbnail image which is what lets the description text sit to the right of the image.

Comment: Thanks so Much Brian, although i dont really understand, at least you have narrowed it down for me, SO the error stems from the plugin? which has been working fine for years! lol i may have to get a developer to have a look as suggested, and i only understand basic css.

Comment: You're very welcome, yeah for some reason the plugin isn't including the stylesheet on that template - you could copy the relevant styles over to your main stylesheet - the following rule should do the trick :) `.wpp-thumbnail{ display:inline; float:left; margin:0 5px 0 0; border:none; }`.

Comment: Who is the biggest legend on Stackoverflow??? 
BRIAN!!!! 
heheh thanks buddy that code did the trick instantly!

Im just messing around now trying to get the second of text line to be bold and smaller like it was before. "799 samples claimed today"

True legend cant thank you enough!

Comment: Sorry to be a pin in your butt Brian, any ideas how to add the css to make the second line bold and smaller etc, i added the following css to the style-sheet but it deosnt make a difference?
thanks!

.post-stats {
   display:block;
   font-size:9px;
   font-weight:bold;
  }

Thanks!

Comment: This seemed to work for me: `.wpp-views {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}`